# How do you change a signing user to a CarbonCopy user via the API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document with a number of signers attached, I would like to convert those people who haven't signed into CC recipients of the document via the API.

The first method I tried was to remove the signers and then add the CC recipients.
This doesn't work as by the time I add the CC recipients the document is complete and can't be modified.

If I add the CC recipients first removing the signers has the effect of removing the CC recipients as they share the same email address.

Method 2 should work but the API doesn't seem to distinguish between the type of recipient being removed.

```
$recipients = new Recipients();
$recipients->setCarbonCopies($ccRecipientsAdd->toArray());
$envelopeApi->createRecipient($accountId, $envelopeId, $recipients);

$recipients = new Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners($signersToRemove->toArray());
$envelopeApi->deleteRecipients($accountId, $envelopeId, $recipients);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first add CC recipients with unique recipientId. Then you need to delete the signers who have not completed signing ceremony by signer's recipientId by calling

```
DELETE /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}
```

Since recipientId are different for Signers and CC recipients so removing Signer will not remove the CC recipient.

Comment: After giving this a go adding CC recipients seems to be hit or miss.
I don't suppose you know what the format of the `recipientId` field is?

Comment: Ideally recipientId is an integer

Comment: What do you mean ideally? I am using guuid's. Do you know what the actual field requirements are?

Comment: May be I misunderstood your qs, what do you mean by "I don't suppose you know what the format of the recipientId field is"? What I meant was normally recipientId is put as an integer and recipientGuid is a Guid generated by Docusign. Whenever you want to do any operation related to recipient in DocuSign via API then you would refer a recipientId.

Comment: I don't think you misunderstood. I am setting the recipientid to an internally generated guid. Do you know if there are any details for this field, i.e. what will it and what wont it accept? Could I pass in a 1,000 character string for example or does it just accept a 3 digit number?